# Restoring crashed Mysql Database from files

Tags: mysql, database

I have a VPS server that was hosting a WordPress that has crashed and I think must be deleted. No backups were made. I managed to setup a rescue mode and salvage WP site data via FTP.

Because Mysql server cannot be started or reinstalled in this state, I cannot generate database dump.  All I can do is manually copy DB files over FTP.

The DB folder contains:

One db.opt file and many .frm and .ibd files.

If I zip this folder and try to import it into Phpmyadmin (MAMP), on local machine 0 tables are imported.

What is the way to get this done?

Comment: It's going to be a long process but this worth a try https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57157/191579 .

Comment: Looks like you had a INNODB Database, so you will also need ibdata1 from the data directory, thats where most of the database actually resides

Comment: I can see ibdata1 file there. Not sure what workflow to follow in Phpmyadmin